# Where can I find "Hakata Tonkotsu Ramens" light novels in English?

Tags: hakata-tonkotsu-ramens

I started watching the anime, and it's really interesting so I wanted to read the original, the light novels, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I don't find any news whether the light novel has been licensed, so I'm not sure there's a way to read the English version legally...

Answer (score -1):

You have the unlicensed translation: not good in the hood . url 
"This series is currently not licensed for official English releases at this time" 
Finding a physical copy? Not going to happen unless a translation gets licensed.

Comment: Please don't provide unlicensed translation because it's a copyright infringement and piracy, which this community doesn't support.